# Creating a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I am trying to create a node as shown in the below figure. Could anyone help me how to create it?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, rectangle split horizontal, draw]{\nodepart{two}ReadInput};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

Following code shows an improved version of previous code. It shows font and colors more similar to OP's example.

A second solution is also provided. This one uses a regular node with larger `inner xsep` and a `path picture` option which draws inner lines. This solution avoids to use `\nodepart{two}` inside node's contents and offers a better control over size of lateral boxes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=3,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        font=\sffamily,
        color = cyan!80!black,
        draw,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=orange
    }
]
\node[mynode]{\nodepart{two}ReadInput};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        color = cyan!80!black,
        draw,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=orange,
        inner xsep=4mm,
        path picture={%
            \draw ([xshift=-2mm]path picture bounding box.north east)--([xshift=-2mm]path picture bounding box.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=2mm]path picture bounding box.north west)--([xshift=2mm]path picture bounding box.south west);},
    }
]
\node[mynode]{ReadInput};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here are some suggestions: I think the second part should be of fixed width, the font should be in `\sffamily` and the node should have a shade color. Anyway, +1 :)

Comment: How do I change the width of the rectangles on the end.

Comment: @AkhileshThothara On second solution, the width is automaticaly adjusted to text width, but if you want to impose some width you can use `minimum width` or `text width` options.